# Run SDK in DJI Phantom 4 PRO+

Tags: android, ios, dji-sdk

I need support and information please.

I have one  DJI Phantom 4 PRO+, i want to run the SDK, but this drone have integrate a device with the application of DJI by the default exist any way to run a external application, i try to connect other device and run the sample SDK application but, i can´t, please i need some help of information to test the SDK in this device .

Is posible use the SDK in this device, or can i desactivate the device and connect other device?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

DJI Phantom 4 Pro has a custom launcher on the Android device that blocks 3rd party apps from installing and activating.

If you want to run apps you should invest in a Phantom 4 Pro (non-plus), you will be much happier I think.

Comment: Do you mean that PRO+ blocks 3rd party apps?

Comment: Yes: the Pro+ has a controller with integrated screen (and runs fixed Android apps, a bit like a CrystalSky device you could buy separately. You do not connect a tablet or mobile phone as the screen, in fact, you cannot do this at all with the Pro+ controller, I believe.